# In Oracle SQL, compare string date column with today's date. Considering only Month and Day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a user table in which the birthdate Column is string type with date **pattern = '19910511' (YYYYMMDD)**. How can i compare this column with today's date only using Month and day. The problem is the pattern of birthdate column.
I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT UDATANASCIMENTO as birthDate FROM USERS WHERE to_char(UDATANASCIMENTO, 'MMDD') = to_char(sysdate, 'MMDD')
```

But it doesn't work as the formating is the issue. Any ideas please ?

Comment: I don't see anything related to PL/SQL, so I will remove the tag and edit the title. Please edit again if my guess is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
where substr(udatanascimento, 5) = to_char(sysdate, 'mmdd')
```

The left-hand side extracts the substring that begins at the fifth character of the "birthdate" column value; it's a string-to-string operation, so `to_char()` has nothing to do with it. Of course, you need `to_char()` on `sysdate`.

Comment: Yes its correct, I just did not think substr is the key. many thanks to you